# How to use a button to select values on radiobutton for python?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I can't set the value and, after, run my function with my select radio. Someone can help me?
When i click the button for show me the functions "rendafixa" and "rendavariavel", nothing happens. but it was supposed to show me the "funfou rf" or "funfou rv".
How can i fix this?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fonttitulo = ('Arial', '15', 'bold',)
        self.fonttxt = ('Calibri', '10', 'bold')
        self.fontent = ('Calibri', '9')

        self.ctntitulo = Frame(master)
        self.ctntitulo['padx'] = 20
        self.ctntitulo['pady'] = 5
        self.ctntitulo.pack()

        self.ctnsubtitle = Frame(master)
        self.ctnsubtitle['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnsubtitle['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnsubtitle.pack()

        self.ctnnome = Frame(master)
        self.ctnnome['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnnome['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnnome.pack()

        self.ctnrsptnome = Frame(master)
        self.ctnrsptnome['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnrsptnome['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnrsptnome.pack()

        self.ctnqstnativo = Frame(master)
        self.ctnqstnativo['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnqstnativo['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnqstnativo.pack()

        self.ctnativo = Frame(master)
        self.ctnativo['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnativo['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnativo.pack()

        self.ctnslctativo = Frame(master)
        self.ctnslctativo['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnslctativo['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnslctativo.pack()

        self.ctnrandom = Frame(master)
        self.ctnrandom['padx'] = 20
        self.ctnrandom['pady'] = 5
        self.ctnrandom.pack()

        self.title = Label(self.ctntitulo, font = self.fonttitulo, text="Ganhos Futuros", width=40)
        self.title.pack()

        self.subtitle = Label(self.ctnsubtitle, font=self.fonttxt, text='Seu ajudante de investimentos', width=30)
        self.subtitle.pack()

        self.lblnome = Label(self.ctnnome, text='Qual seu nome? ', font=self.fonttxt, width=20)
        self.lblnome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.entnome = Entry(self.ctnnome, textvariable = '', font=self.fontent, width=10)
        self.entnome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.rsptnome = Label(self.ctnrsptnome, text="", width=30, font=self.fonttxt)

        self.radioValue = IntVar()
        self.radioValue.set(1)


        self.btnnome = Button(self.ctnnome, text="Vamos lá!", font=self.fonttxt, width=10)
        self.btnnome['command'] = self.aparecer_ativos
        self.btnnome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblativos = Label(self.ctnqstnativo, text="Selecione seu ativo", font=self.fonttxt, width=20)


    def aparecer_ativos(self):

        self.nome = self.entnome.get()
        self.rsptnome.config(text="Deixa eu te ajudar, {}!".format(self.nome))
        self.rsptnome.pack()

        self.lblativos.pack()

        self.radio_one = Radiobutton(self.ctnativo, text="Renda Fixa", variable = self.radioValue, value = 1)
        self.radio_two = Radiobutton(self.ctnativo, text="Renda Variável", variable = self.radioValue, value = 2)

        self.radio_one.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.radio_two.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblrandom = Label(self.ctnrandom, text='', width=10, font=self.fonttxt)

        self.btnslctativo = Button(self.ctnslctativo, text='Confirmar', width=10, command=self.qual_ativo)
        self.btnslctativo.pack()

    def qual_ativo(self):
        self.ativozin = self.radioValue.get()
        if self.ativozin == 1:
            return self.rendafixa
        if self.ativozin == 2:
            return self.rendavariavel

    def rendafixa(self):
        self.lblrandom.config(text='funfou rf')
        self.lblrandom.pack()

    def rendavariavel(self):
        self.lblrandom.config(text='funfou rv')
        self.lblrandom.pack()

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So, how can I display my function "rendafixa" or "rendavariavel" on accordingly my radioValue?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. Based on the indentation, it seems there is some missing code.

Comment: Why are you returning from a button callback? Did you just want to call the functions?

Comment: I just want to run the functions accordingly to my radio-button choice. How can i do it?

Comment: Change `return self.rendafixa` to `self.rendafixa()` and `return self.rendavariavel` to `self.rendavariavel()`